# In a Razor view how can I insert the page title without a <?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, razor

In my ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor layout view I want my page title to always be "My Website" and if ViewBag.Title is set I want to append that to the title, using a hyphen as a separator. I want this code to be on a single line

This code fails :

```
<title>My Website @if( string.IsNullOrEmpty( ViewBag.Title) == false){ - @ViewBag.Title}</title>
```

With

> The if block is missing a closing "}"
>   character.  Make sure you have a
>   matching "}" character for all the "{"
>   characters within this block, and that
>   none of the "}" characters are being
>   interpreted as markup.

Presumably because @: assumes that the rest of the line is markup. I can't use a span tag to help Razor because the browser title becomes "My Website - span Home span".

Yes I can spread this over two or three lines, but I don't want to. This works but is it my only option with Razor ?

```
<title>My Website @if( string.IsNullOrEmpty( ViewBag.Title) == false){ @: - @ViewBag.Title
}</title>
```

Comment: You could apply the `-` to the title in an ActionFilter, and keep the view a little neater

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you need [razor explicit text markup](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx)

```
 <title>My Website @if( string.IsNullOrEmpty( ViewBag.Title) == false){ <text>-</text> @ViewBag.Title}</title>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the [`<text>` pseudo-tag](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx).

```
<title>My Website @if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Title)) { <text>- @ViewBag.Title</text> }</title>
```

Comment: Yes that's it cheers, both you and archil gave me instant correct answers, thanks both