# setting the page title, meta info in a view in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am very new to MVC and I am updating a web form application to mvc. I have a shared layout (masterpage in webforms), I would like to set the meta and title information per view but I see no options for this. thanks for any help.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Typically, in your layout, you'll have something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
     <!-- the rest omitted for brevity -->
```

The important part is `@ViewBag.Title`. This bit of razor syntax encodes and writes the value of `ViewBag.Title`. `ViewBag` is a property on all razor views to a dynamic type that uses the  `ViewData` dictionary as its backing store. `ViewData` is just a dictionary where you can store random stuff that you want to use in your view.

In your controller, layout, or view, you can get or set `ViewBag.Title`. Here's an example of how to set it in a view that uses your layout (called `_Layout.cshtml` in this example):

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "My View's Title";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

You can access the model metadata from `ViewData.ModelMetadata`. In this example, I enumerate the properties of the model and display the names:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
  <li>@property.PropertyName</li>
}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6):

In your method of controller.

`ViewData["Title"] = "this is page one title";`

in you view, have this.
`@ViewData["Title"])`

if title is html, it should be `@html.raw(ViewData["TopMessage"])`

Razor engine is better for mvc, so I recommend you try razor when you create a new project. hope it help you.

Answer (score 4):

I like to set page titles dynamically using the action and controller names. You can use a library like [Humanizer](https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer) to convert "SomeActionName" into "Some action name":

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString GetPageTitle(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        var actionName = helper.GetRouteDataValue("action");
        var controllerName = helper.GetRouteDataValue("controller");

        return new MvcHtmlString(controllerName.Humanize() + " - " + actionName.Humanize());
    }

    private static string GetRouteDataValue(this HtmlHelper helper, string value)
    {
        return helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values[value].ToString();
    }
}
```

and then in your _Layout:

```
<title>@Html.GetPageTitle()</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Viewbag.Title`
These articles look relevant and will give you some pointers:

- [How do I access a ViewBag.Title after it has been set by the underlying View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216600/how-do-i-access-a-viewbag-title-after-it-has-been-set-by-the-underlying-view)
- [In a Razor view how can I insert the page title without a <?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613880/in-a-razor-view-how-can-i-insert-the-page-title-without-a)