# How can I add result from searching to title in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, search

I wanted to add search query name to header on my subpage so for example if someone will type John in search box the page that he/she receives is: Searching results for: John

Home Controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(string searching)
        {
            IEnumerable<Book> books = from t in Book.allBooks select t;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searching))
            {
                books = books.Where(a => a.Title.ToLower().Contains(searching.ToLower()));
            }

            return View(books.ToList());
        }
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<li class="d-none d-lg-block justify-content-center" style="align-self: center; padding-right: 10px">

                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
                    {
                        <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right: 5px"> </i>
                        @Html.TextBox("searching")
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                    }
                </li>
```

Search.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            @*@Html.TextBox("searching")
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />*@
        }

        @if (Model.Count() == 0)
        {
            <h2 style="margin-top: 30px">Not found any book with this name</h2>
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 align-items-center" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <img src="~/Content/BookImages/@item.Image" class="img-thumbnail" style="height: 400px; width: 250px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <strong>@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", "Home", new { id = item.Id }, null)</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                @item.WriterFirstName
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                @item.WriterLastName
            </div>
        </div>
            }
        }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You could create a ViewModel with the list and header in it as properties, or put the header in the ViewBag

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586030/setting-the-page-title-meta-info-in-a-view-in-asp-net-mvc-4).

Answer (score 0):

This could work for you:

```
public ActionResult Search(string searching)
        {
            IEnumerable<Book> books = from t in Book.allBooks select t;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searching))
            {
                books = books.Where(a => a.Title.ToLower().Contains(searching.ToLower()));
            }
            ViewBag.SearchTerm = searching;

            return View(books.ToList());
        }
```

And in your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            @*@Html.TextBox("searching")
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />*@
        }

        @if (Model.Count() == 0)
        {
            <h2 style="margin-top: 30px">Not found any book with this name</h2>
        }
        else
        {
            <h2 style="margin-top: 30px">Search results for: @ViewBag.SearchTerm</h2>
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 align-items-center" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <img src="~/Content/BookImages/@item.Image" class="img-thumbnail" style="height: 400px; width: 250px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <strong>@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", "Home", new { id = item.Id }, null)</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                @item.WriterFirstName
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                @item.WriterLastName
            </div>
        </div>
            }
        }
```

Mind you, this is a quick and dirty solution. The proper one would be to create a ViewModel and add both books and the search term.

```
public class SearchBookViewModel {
    public IEnumerable<Book> Books {get; set;}
    public string SearchTerm {get; set;}
}
```

If you can't change the ViewModel then go with the ViewBag. The bad thing about the ViewBag, is that if someone changes the code in the controller, then you will only find out during runtime.